# Django in Colab - can't access admin login page

Tags: python, django, google-colaboratory

I am trying to start a new project on djago in google colab. I have created new project and also pasted-
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['colab.research.google.com','*']` to `settings.py`.

And using this:

```
from google.colab.output import eval_js
print(eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(8000)"))
```

to get the external link to access that port.
And managed to run the server by running this-
`!python manage.py runserver 8000`
But I can only land on the *The install worked successfully! Congratulations!* page.
And Created a super user using this-
`!python manage.py createsuperuser`
But I can't access the admin page and other pages. Please Help me.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Check the file `settings.py`. It must contain code

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).